# Rails 4 + Datatables: Empty table displays strange double text

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a `DataTable` in my view that displays strangely when the table is empty.  Every other row has what looks like an offset `text-shadow` but I don't see anything in my css that would do that?  This issue also goes away once there is an additional column on the table.

[image]

**html** (example of first row with double-text "Current Weight")

```
<tr class="profile-row odd" role="row" data-dt-row="0" style="height: 30px;">
    <td class="profile-header" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="0">
        Current Weight
    </td>
</tr>
```

**css**

```
element.style {
    height: 30px;
}
.profile-row {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
Inherited from table.profile-table-table.specialest.dataTable.no-footer.DTFC_Cloned
table {
    border-spacing: 1em 0;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'open sans';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 20px;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

....

```
element.style {
}
div.DTFC_RightBodyWrapper tbody tr:first-child th, div.DTFC_RightBodyWrapper tbody tr:first-child td, div.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper tbody tr:first-child th, div.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
}

table.dataTable td, table.dataTable th {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
table.dataTable td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table.dataTable td, table.dataTable th {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.profile-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    text-align: right;
}
p, ol, ul, td {
    font-family: 'open sans';
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
td, th {
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
td, th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
Inherited from tr.profile-row.odd
.profile-row {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    text-align: center;
}
Inherited from table.profile-table-table.specialest.dataTable.no-footer.DTFC_Cloned
table {
    border-spacing: 1em 0;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'open sans';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 20px;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the css output of the page ?

Comment: For the entire page?  Or for the elements in question?

Comment: Just the elements in question. When you inspect it in chrome you get all the css that applies and where it came from. That should give you an indication of where to look.